# multithreading and JDBC

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I use java and oracle and I want to use 2 threads to read the records from the result set : the first thread is to retrieve the records and the second to read these records.But by this code I always obtained just the first record any idea please?

```
    public class JavaApplication13 {


 public static  volatile boolean finished =false;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {


    final PipedWriter writer=new PipedWriter();
    final PipedReader reader = new PipedReader();
    reader.connect(writer);

    //thread2: afficher 


    final Thread thread2=new Thread("lire")
    {
        public void run(){
            try{
                while(!finished)
                {

                  int l=reader.read();
                    System.out.println(l);

                }
            }catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    };



    //thread1:récupére de la base
   final Thread thread1=new Thread("DB"){
        public void run(){
            try{

   Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/stage","root", "");
Statement s=conn.createStatement();
     String sql = "select idetudiant from etudiant";
ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery(sql);  

            while(rs.next()){
            int k= rs.getInt("idetudiant");
             writer.write(k);

            }
               finished=true;
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    };

   thread2.start();
   thread1.start();
   thread2.join();



}
```

}

Comment: table: etudiant  //always this code display 1 but in the table there are 1 , 5, 42 ,10....

Comment: JDBC does not allow to use objects (connections, result sets) concurrently.

Comment: I believe that you might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before re-editing your question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a buffer between the two threads; this is a feature of pipes.

So what happens is that `thread1` puts a lot of data into the pipe's buffer and then sets `finished` to `true`.

When enough data is in the pipe, `thread2` will start. At that time, `finished` is `true`, so the thread will just read the first item and quit.

Solution: Get rid of the variable. Flush and close the pipe `writer` in `thread1` when it's done:

```
final Thread thread1=new Thread("DB"){
    public void run(){
        try{
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        writer.close(); // send EOF to other thread
    }
};
```

In `thread2`, read from the pipe `reader` until `read()` returns EOF (-1):

```
final Thread thread2=new Thread("lire")
{
    public void run(){
        try{
            while(true)
            {

                int l=reader.read();
                if(-1 == l) break; // EOF
                System.out.println(l);

            }
        }catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();}
    }
};
```

Comment: Alternatively, use wait/notify on appropriate objects shared between the two threads...

Comment: @BadZen: That's pretty low level. I'd say a `Queue` with an `ExecutorService` would be an alternative for the pipe.

Comment: Yeah, was kind of taking the pipes scheme as a given.  One essential difference - Future is good for when there's a single result.  With streams you can get multiple results as they come.   But I guess it is "low-level" or basic and prone to the sort of mistake above (spinning the CPU on a condition variable without waiting), etc.